# Materializecss's checkbox input not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox, materialize

I am building the Simon game, and I'm using two sets of `checkbox` `inputs` from the Materialize.css library.

As shown in the official [docs](http://materializecss.com/forms.html), here's the snippet for the `checkbox` -

```
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="test5" />
  <label for="test5">Red</label>
</p>
```

The problem is, it doesn't seem to work at all when I try to detect if the `checkbox` is `checked`, using jQuery. I have tried both `is(":checked")` and `prop("checked")`, but neither works.

```js
/**
 * Created by manishgiri on 12/26/16.
 */
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($("#start").is(":checked")) {
        console.log("inside");
        console.log("Start is checked");
    }
    if($("#start").prop("checked")) {
        console.log("inside");
        console.log("Start is checked");
    }
    //console.log("outside");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="start" />
      <label for="start">Start</label>
    </p>
```

Here's the complete app on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Nyxx/pen/0bc900d390f69ac3732734af07e6fb7d). I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is functioning as it is written - on `$(document).ready` (DOM load), the checkbox is being looked at to see whether or not it is checked. Because the code is only run once, it won't do anything when the checkbox is changed.

To get the behavior you want, you need to use the `onchange` event on the input. Here it is jQuery-style:

```js
/**
 * Created by manishgiri on 12/26/16.
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#start').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      console.log('Start is checked');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="start" />
  <label for="start">Start</label>
</p>
```